# Objective-c: Calling [self message] on a base class is invoking the descendant method

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, superclass

I just started learning this, so sorry if this has some obvious solution I still can't grasp.

I have these two classes:

```
@implementation Person
-(void)saySomething:(NSString*) something {
    NSLog(@"%@",something);
}
-(void)yellSomething:(NSString*) something {
    [self saySomething:[something uppercaseString]];
}
@end
```

and

```
@implementation ShoutingPerson : Person

-(void)saySomething:(NSString*)something {
    [super yellSomething:something];
}

@end
```

This is causing a circular reference call because `saySomething` is **always** being called on the descendant class.

How can I make `yellSomething` invoke the `saySomething` method on `Person` class instead of the descendant class ?

Comment: This case you could do it by just deleting ShoutingPerson's saySomething method and Person's yellSomething method.
 But I suppose that this is just an example, you want to know how dispatch static messages right?

Comment: Actually no. I just was considering `self` behavior being the same of `this` in other languages.

Comment: 'self' and 'this' are the same. What's not the same is method binding. I'm guessing you're coming from C++ which is statically early bound, while ObjC (and most OO languages actually) is dynamically late bound.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I misunderstood static messages for static methods, sorry. Being able to tell which class in the hierarchy `self` is bound to is what you call static messages ?

Comment: static message means that the body of the method depends on the type of the reference, and not on the type of the object (like in C++).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jonathan says, you really should avoid this if at all possible.  It's just a bad design to need this functionality.  If your base class is intended to be subclassed, its documentation should spell out which methods **must** be overridden and which others *may* be overridden.  Anything else should **not** be overridden, to avoid problems like this.

That said, if you are in a very unusual situation where it is necessary (perhaps you're stuck working with 3rd party code that you cannot refactor), it is possible.  But it's not pretty.  You need to call [objc_msgSendSuper](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSendSuper) or [objc_msgSendSuper_stret](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSendSuper_stret) manually, after constructing an instance of [struct objc_super](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCFBBGA) pointing to `self` and `YourBaseClass`.

Note that if you're coming from C++ the default behaviour there is the same - if you call `SomeFunction()` from your base class and it's a virtual method, the subclass's override will be executed.  You would have to prefix your call to spell out the class explicitly, e.g. `MyBaseClass::SomeFunction()`.  There's no direct equivalent for that in Objective-C - I'd say because it's just such a bad idea generally.

Comment: I intentionally left out mentioning `objc_msgSendSuper` because it's definitely a more advanced topic. :)

Answer (score 10):

You don't. This is how inheritance is supposed to work in Objective-C. Instead, you should document in your base class that the default implementation of `-yellSomething:` just calls `-saySomething:`. It then becomes a subclass responsibility not to screw up the stack trace.

If you really want to be able to change what calls what, have a third method in your base class:

`-vocalizeSomething: (NSString *)what loudly: (BOOL)loudly;`

It's the one to speak the words. Both `-saySomething:` and `-yellSomething:` call through to it directly rather than calling each other. Then the subclass can safely override either method to call the other, or call `vocalizeSomething:loudly:` without creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Understood, thanks. It's quite different from `this`.... Can you provide some further reading material ?

Comment: There's a lot of books out there you can read to get you started with Objective-C. I can't really recommend any personally because I didn't go that route.

Comment: If you aren't sure you can still start from Apple's documentation.