# ObjC: using "super" in conjunction with overriding

Tags: objective-c, overriding, super

I have a class A and a class B which is a subclass of A. Both have the following methods:

```
-(void)anotherMethod{
    // implementation of A or B
}

-(void)aMethod{
    @try{
        [super aMethod];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e){
    }
    [self anotherMethod];
}
```

Now: if I call `[instanceOfClassB aMethod]` the instruction `[self anotherMethod]` contained in A's implementation of `aMethod` calls B's `anotherMethod` (since it's overridden) instead of A's one. How can I make A's implementation of `aMethod` call A's implementation of `anotherMethod`?

Comment: This should help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670919/objective-c-calling-self-message-on-a-base-class-is-invoking-the-descendant-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is doing a method swizzling before (and immediately after) calling super in order to replace the subclass implementation with the superclass one. It requires "hacking" the runtime, that's right, but I haven't found anything simpler than this. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[ClassB class]]) {
    [super anotherMethod];
} else {
    [self anotherMethod];
}
```

Comment: Nice. The problem is that A doesn't even know B exists (and it shouldn't). I could "reverse" your code by inverting the if/else block using A, but A's superclass doesn't implement anotherMethod... I'd avoid this issue by trying performSelector: but I don't know if I can call it on super... I mean: is [super performSelector:@selector(anotherMethod)] (called in a try/catch block) valid?

Comment: @user732274 it is, but why would you need that? Why not just forward-declare class B? I know that's ugly, but it's not rare in Cocoa.

Comment: I need a solution which is the most flexible. Anyway, calling performSelector: on super doesn't solve the problem: the subclass implementation is called.

Comment: @user732274 By the way, if you don't want to forward-declare `@class B;`, neither do you want to use `[ClassB class]`, you can still have `objc_getClass("ClassB")` or test for `if (![self isMemberOfClass:[AlassA class]])`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:
This person had the same problem as yours.

[Objective-c: Calling [self message] on a base class is invoking the descendant method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670919/objective-c-calling-self-message-on-a-base-class-is-invoking-the-descendant-m)